# Erro "O PHP não tem ativado o suporte ao MySQL" na instalação em host local

Tags: php, mysql, galeria

Estava tentando instalar a galeria coppermine no meu localhost, utilizo o XAMPP pra isso. Só que no meio da instalação me deparei com o seguinte erro: **O PHP não tem ativado o suporte ao MySQL.**

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar? Agradeço desde já!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a tela de instalação. Talvez eu nao esteja sabendo configurar?

Comment: Pode ser que esteja falando do [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.setup.php)

Comment: Voce sabe como posso arrumar isso?